# Show that $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x,y)=x+y$ maps an open set to open set and a dense set to a dense set.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The given function $f(x,y)=x+y$

I have to show that this function maps open set to open set

S**solution i tried**- Here we have to show that $f$ maps open set to open sets which implies that $f$ is an open map.I am trying to prove the answer from backward direction .According to **open mapping theorem** in functional analysis  states that

**every surjective continuous linear operator between Banach spaces is an open map**

here given given $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are both Banach spaces,thus i have to prove that $f$ is linear operator and surjective

$$f(a(x_1,y_1)+b(x_2,y_2))=f(ax_1+bx_2,ay_1+by_2)$$
$$\Rightarrow f(ax_1+bx_2,ay_1+by_2)=ax_1+bx_2+ay_1+by_2 $$
$$\Rightarrow  f(ax_1+bx_2,ay_1+by_2)=a(x_1,y_1)+b(x_2,y_2) $$
$$\Rightarrow  f(ax_1+bx_2,ay_1+by_2)=af(x_1,y_1)+bf(x_2,y_2)$$

Thus from this we can say that $f$ is a linear functional ,now i have to prove that $f$ is surjective and this is the point where i stuck please give me hint how can i prove that $f$ is surjective.

Thankyou

Comment: To prove it's surjective examine what happens when $x=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a very powerful result to prove something trivial. Just prove that the image is open with the definition. For every point in the image, find a nbhd still in the image. Same with density, show that given any point in $\mathbb{R}$ you can get as close as you want with images of elements of a dense set in the plane.
By the way, surjectivity is trivial by taking $f(x,0)=x$

P.S. I mean, you’re not wrong, I just like to prove things directly when I can, instead of using powerful abstract tools from functional analysis

Comment: I think you would like to see this great proof: https://mathoverflow.net/a/42519/129831

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch how did this answer my question?

Comment: @TheStudent My comment is a light-hearted joke because the answerer says "I just like to prove things directly when I can, instead of using powerful abstract tools" -- Your question was already answered by tommy!

Comment: But still i have some confusion in this answer

Comment: Ahahahahaha, “unfortunately FLT is not powerful enough to prove irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$” totally broke me!

Comment: @Thestudent Well, as I said you can nuke it using open mapping theorem, and noting the surjectivity comes from taking $f(x,0)$. Otherwise, you can prove it directly through the definition of open set. What is it that you don’t understand, precisely?

Answer (score 1):

Let $R=(a,b)\times (c,d).$ Then

$$f(R)= \bigcup_{x\in (a,b)}f(\{x\}\times (a,b))=\bigcup_{x\in (a,b)}(x+a,x+b).$$

The set on the right is a union of open intervals, hence is open in $\mathbb R.$

Thus $f(R)$ is open for every open rectangle $R.$ Since an arbitrary open set in $\mathbb R^2$ is a union of open rectangles, we're done.

Comment: does this function also maps closed set to closed set?